# Exception while calling web service----java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: android

I am developing one application through which i am calling web
service.
      The web Service is hosted on the local machine,but while calling
web service i got
      java.net.SocketException: Permission denied this bug.
                    Mentioned internet permission in the manifest file
although, i am getting this.
      I am looking forward for positive response.

Thanks in Advance.
     Regards

Comment: plz provide some code on which you work..it would be good for solving your problem

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have the `INTERNET` permission in the wrong place in your manifest.